# Rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Could not get information about the resource: resource name may not be empty

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I Installed Helm 3 on my windows laptop where i have kube config configured as well. But when i try to install my local helm chart, i;m getting the below error.

```
Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: could not get information about the resource: resource name may not be empty
```

I tried `helm ls --all --all-namespaces` but i don't see anything. Please help me!

Comment: Can you run `kubectl get all --all-namespaces`  and check if any resource exists that you want to create by helm chart?

Comment: Instead of install try `helm template` to check what is rendered and compare what you have in your cluster.

Comment: I am having the same issue.

Comment: I'm a little confused about the error message, but I was able to fix mine. I simply had a template file for a ConfigMap that was defining a name with a particular value but I didn't have that value defined in my values.yaml.

Comment: @Skanda Can you check if the your helm chart creates the same resource twice ?

Answer (score 11):

I think you have to check if you left off any resource without `- name:`

Comment: Yes, same here. This can easily go undetected because `helm template` does not return any warnings at all and instead happily returns the manifest with no `name: `

Comment: in my case, the name got accidentally indented under `label`. Thanks for the answer. And `helm template` won't be reporting such typo.

Answer (score 2):

Had same error message. I solved the problem using `helm lint` on the folder of a dependecy charts that I just added. That pointed me to some bad assignment of values.
Beware: `helm lint` on the parent folder didn't highlight any problem in the dependencies folders.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. In values.yaml I had

name:

and in deployment.yaml I tried to access this "name" via {{ .Values.name }}. I found out, that {{ .Values.name }} doesn't work for me at all. I had to use {{ Chart.Name }} in deployment.yaml as the built-in object. ref: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/builtin_objects/

If you want to access the "name", you can put it into values.yaml for example like this:

something:
name:

and them access it from deployment.yaml (for example) like {{ .Values.something.name }}

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is already the same resource existing in your namespace where you are trying to install or in your helm chart you are trying to create the same resource twice.
Try to create a new namespace and try helm install if you still face the issue then definitely there is some issue with your helm install.

Comment: No. he pasted his output that there is nothing in the namespace.

Comment: @arsen then I suppose the helm chart is creating the same resource twice and that might be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error, the fix was to correct the sub-chart name in values.yaml file of main chart.

Answer (score 0):

Best bet would be to run `helm template .` in the chart directory and verify that name or namespace fields are not empty. This was the case with me atleast.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, one of the deployments you removed left behind a clusterole.

Check if you have one with `kubectl get clusterole`

Once you find it, you can delete it with `kubectl delete clusterrole <clusterrolename>`